# LinqToEntites Update,Delete,Insert is not working with LinqDataSource Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to update my LinqDataSource Object through my GridPanel

```
    <asp:LinqDataSource 
    ID="LinqDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="IntraNET_Prototype.IntraNetEntities"
    TableName="EmployeeList" 
    EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" />
```

Any time I'm trying to update something when my GridPanel fires the event and triggers the update I get the following Error Message:

> System.Exception: The data context used by LinqDataSource 'LinqDataSource1' must extend DataContext when the Delete, Insert or Update operations are enabled.

I'm using LinqToEntities, any Idea what's going wrong and how to enable that?

Thanks!

Comment: first guess from error is, your context type name is not correct, try copying from class view.

Comment: The Context type name is correct, as it displays all values and data correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinqDataSource` is for 'general' Linq queries.
You can use it but then you have to implement Update and Delete yourself, as the error indicates.

To use an ADO Entities source, use the `EntityDataSource`.

For Linq2Sql, use `SqlDataSource`.